# WebGL Vertex shader is not compiled. Getting ERROR: Missing main() despite having a main() function

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, vertex-shader

I have a simple Tree.js app to play around with shaders. I tested it now I am getting a no `main()` error despite the vertex shader being literally just a `main()`:

```
three.js:12525 THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 0 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Program Info Log: Vertex shader is not compiled.

ERROR: Missing main()

ERROR: Missing main()
```

I have ran this code 1-2 years ago while in uni and it worked fine. Now I am getting this error. I tested on both Chrome and Firefox and also on another computer (both Windows 10). I have no idea what is going on since the shader is empty. Here is a minimal example of what I'm seeing.

I am spinning a local python http server to serve files with: `python -m http.server 8000`

This is `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test tree.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is `main.js`:

```
RESOURCES = [
  ["vert_shader", "http://localhost:8000/shaders/default.vert"],
  ["frag_shader", "http://localhost:8000/shaders/default.frag"]
];

function initialise_scene(resources) {
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x7c7c7c, 0.002);
  
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 30;

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color, 1);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  function defaultShader(r, g, b) {
    return new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        color: {value: new THREE.Vector3(r, g, b)}
      },
      vertexShader: resources["vert_shader"],
      fragmentShader: resources["frag_shader"]
    });
  };

  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4);
  // material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });
  material = defaultShader(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.position.set(-10, 5, -5);
  scene.add(cube);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function load_resources() {
  var promises = []

  for(let r of RESOURCES) {
    promises.push(fetch(r[1], {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then(res => res.text()))
  }

  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(res) {
    let resources = {}
    for(let i in RESOURCES) {
      resources[RESOURCES[i][0]] = res[i]
    }
    return resources
  })
}

load_resources().then(res => initialise_scene(res))
```

This is `shaders/default.vert`:

```
void main() {
}
```

This is `shaders/default.frag`:

```
uniform vec3 color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

After adding a `console.log(resources)` I found that the shaders are loaded as just empty strings. This confuses me a lot, since the python server I span up to serve the files logs:

```
::1 - - [14/Nov/2022 02:28:41] "GET /shaders/default.vert HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [14/Nov/2022 02:28:41] "GET /shaders/default.frag HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Aren’t `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` supposed to be strings? You’re passing Promises that resolve to Responses.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh you are right, I introduced that bug when simplifying the code. Let me fix it and edit.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Edited. However, after adding a `console.log(resources)` I found that the shaders are loaded as just empty strings.